# Cloudify Web UI can not see any log/event

Tags: cloudify

Before last weekend, everything went well with my Cloudify Web UI(I am using cloudify 3.3 on Windows 7) and I can find all the logs by simply clicking on the Logs/Events tag. However starting from today, I can't see even 1 line of the logs,  while still can find the logs in my working dir. Hope someone can help me fix it, ty.

Comment: have you upgraded any component of cloudify, or is it the same cloudify 3.3 that used to work before?

Comment: @ChenR no I don't think I made any upgrade and the most weird thing is, it is the exactly same cloudify i worked before. do you have any idea about how to find the logs on web UI itself?

Comment: on the manager machine, `/opt/cloudify-ui/logs/application.log`.
in any case, i can't think of anything general that might cause this.

Comment: @ChenR ty, I found it. seems like nothing wrong with it, it's so weird